# How to find out whether Bootstrap 3 columns have stacked or not

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Supposing we all know that certain bootstrap classes will collapse when the screen reach a certain width (for instance 2 col-md-6 will be side by side on a bigger screen and one on top of the other on a smaller screen).

What I'd like to know is how can I find out (using jQuery or plain old JS) when the column have collapsed? I've been thinking and thought about using the width, however as far as I can tell BS don't explicitly specify the width in many cases, so I kind of discarded that. Secondly I though of using the floating property, but I couldn't get it to work using jQuery.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on what skelly said, you could check the window width to see [what size window bootstrap is calculating](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

```
xs = width < 768px
sm = width ≥ 768px
md = width ≥ 992px
lg = width ≥ 1200px
```

Whether the elements are stacked or not depends on the classes you assigned to the containing element. So, stacking will occur on a `lg`-classed element if the window width is 1200px or less, on a `md`-classed element at 992px or less, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way:

1. Get the parent row and get it's width.
2. Get all the (other) children and get their total width.
3. Compare them.

   ```
   var row_width = 0;
   var children_width = 0;
   var $row = $('.yourclass').parents('.row').first(); // get the row
   if ($row && $row.length != 0) {
       row_width = $row.width();
       $row.children().each(function() {
           if ($(this).length != 0) {
               children_width += $(this).width();
           }
       })
   }

   if (row_width < children_width) {
       // do something
   }
   ```

Comment: this is probably a nicer approach than the other options (assuming you can account for any padding / margins / borders) as it doesn't require any knowledge of which classes were used to style the row children

Answer (score 1):

You could check the window width. At 768 pixels Bootstrap divs are stacked..

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(this).width() < 768) {
    console.log("stacked..");
  }
});
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/100820

Comment: Thanks guys. Funnily enough I hadn't thought of that. Its the trick nicely. Cheers